# Is it possible to use PanGestureRecognizer for tvOS?

Tags: swift, tvos

I just started building first apps for tvOS and I'm curious about its gesture recognition abilities.

My goal is to know the direction and displacement of a finger swipe on the apple tv remote.

I know how I can detect tap or swipe, even the direction of the swipe, but not the displacement, in other words I don't know how many points I moved my finger up/down/left/right.

If anyone knows how to do such thing, please share with me.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is! Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/DetectingButtonPressesandGestures.html) Apple guide for more information.

> Tap gesture recognizers can be used to detect button presses. By
>   default, a tap gesture recognizer is triggered when the Select button
>   is pressed. The allowedPressTypes property is used to specify which
>   buttons trigger the recognizer.

**Examples**

**Detecting the Play/Pause button**

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapped:")
tapRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.PlayPause.rawValue)];
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

**Detecting a swipe gesture**

```
let swipeRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swiped:")
swipeRecognizer.direction = .Right
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRecognizer)
```

To get the location of touches, check the [Getting the Location of Touches](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITouch/locationInView:) section in Apples documentation. You need to use `locationInView` for that.

> Returns the current location of the receiver in the coordinate system
>   of the given view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, didn't realize that it would work the same way as on iOS :)) ended up using good old UIPanGestureRecognizer

Comment: how can you do the same thing in SwiftUI without representable ? since tvOS tells me for everything it is unavailable (no swipe / drag / rotate...)