# Using UITapGestureRecognizer to detect taps in tvOS

Tags: tvos

I'm trying to detect when a user *taps* on touch pad of the Siri Remote (not just clicks).

I've seen online that you should configure the recognizer like so.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * const recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(remoteInteractionDetected:)];
recognizer.allowedTouchTypes = @[@(UITouchTypeIndirect)];
recognizer.allowedPressTypes = @[];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

The selector never fires. If I remove the allowed properties, the recognizer responds to clicks only.

Is this possible?

Edit: It is not like the suggested duplicate, because I am not looking for a particular button press or swipe gesture. All I want to know is when a user touches the touch pad, not actually presses it down. Just like the new tvOS 12 Aerial screen savers show the location on this event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use PanGestureRecognizer for tvOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646272/is-it-possible-to-use-pangesturerecognizer-for-tvos)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the above code works on an actual Apple TV device, but not the tvOS Simulator in Xcode 10.0.